# Android sharing to tumblr via SEND_ACTION : image and caption

Tags: android, android-intent, tumblr, sharing

I want to share from my app on Tumblr app an image and a text. This code do not work :

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Caption http://wonderful.url");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.tumblr");
```

When I post this I can see the image but the caption is empty, I want to have the EXTRA_TEXT in the caption (which contains an URL).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of the current Tumblr Android application. Unfortunately, if you want to include a caption with the image you are sharing then you will have to either use the [Tumblr API directly](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2), or use a third-party library like [Jumblr](https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr).